# How to flip the display order of one of the elements individually using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]I am learning CSS screen layout, and I want to use flex to change the display order of an element. I
have found some tutorials on the Internet and still don't know how to write it, so I can simply change the second

, change the display order from left to right?

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores doloribus dolor ipsum odit beatae voluptates culpa. Doloremque veniam labore pariatur!</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores doloribus dolor ipsum odit beatae voluptates culpa. Doloremque veniam labore pariatur!</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores doloribus dolor ipsum odit beatae voluptates culpa. Doloremque veniam labore pariatur!</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Order from left to right? Ok, is there a left or right when all of the `<li>` are in a column? Also, `<li>` by default flow like a column top to bottom or vertically. A row is left to right or horizontally. Also, you want to change the order of the second `<li>`...ok to what position? First or last? BTW CSS is limited when designing dynamic behavior...so please explain if you'd like this change when the page loads or as a reaction to a user clicking something,

Comment: @ze00ne
Hello~ I hope that the text rendering method of the second li is from right to left, which is displayed when the page is loaded without the user's click to change it.

Comment: Ok, that's simple see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71556748/2813224)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you looking for something like that

```css
.flexed {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.flexed div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.reversed{
flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center"> <h4>Without riversed row</h4> </div>
<div  class="flexed" >
  <div style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">2</div>
  <div style="background-color:orange;">3</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">4</div>
</div>



<div style="text-align:center"> <h4>With riversed row</h4> </div>
<div class="flexed reversed" >
  <div style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div style="background-color:pink;">2</div>
  <div style="background-color:orange;">3</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">4</div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center"> <h4>With 2 only riversed row</h4> </div>
<div class="flexed " >
  <div style="background-color:red;">1</div>
  <div class="flexed reversed">
  <div style="background-color:pink;">2</div>
  <div style="background-color:orange;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have checked the method you provided on the Internet!
It seems that it can only reverse all the order, but what I want to achieve today is that I only want the order of the item in the middle to be reversed from right to right Left rendering only, not all items in reverse orde

Comment: updated my answer , with only middle part reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The actual letters right to left is easily accomplished with the [`<bdo>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdo) element. Just wrap the text in a `<bdo>` and add the `dir` attribute and the value of `"rtl"`.

```
<bdo dir='rtl'>Text to reverse</bdo>
```

The text is changed from Latin to English to clearly demonstrate the reversed text.

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Did you know that more frozen bananas are sold right here on this boardwalk than anywhere in the OC? You burn down the storage unit? Oh, most definitely. What a fun, sexy time for you.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p><bdo dir='rtl'>Did you know that more frozen bananas are sold right here on this boardwalk than anywhere in the OC? You burn down the storage unit? Oh, most definitely. What a fun, sexy time for you.</bdo></p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Did you know that more frozen bananas are sold right here on this boardwalk than anywhere in the OC? You burn down the storage unit? Oh, most definitely. What a fun, sexy time for you.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```